# When did Hondo Ohnaka first appear?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, star-wars-rebels

After watching Rebels and Clone Wars, both of which had Hondo, it lead me to wonder where he appeared first? Is it in either of those series, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hondo Ohnaka first appeared in *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*, specifically in the episode "**Dooku Captured**." As the name implies, Hondo and his pirate gang are able to capture Count Dooku, forcing Obi-Wan and Anakin to rescue him.

[image: Dooku Captured]

https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dooku_Captured